# Amazon Lambda - unable to make a http json request using python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

What I currently have is something like (endpoints/params are valid, I checked them using another tool)

```
from urllib import request
...
data = {"name":"abc", "fireDate":"123", "endLocationName":"home"}
request.post("http://someurl.com", json=data)
```

However, the alexa responds with

> there is a problem with the requested skills response

Nothing is outputed on the AWS X-Ray.

Answer (score 4):

There is no [`urllib.request.post`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/urllib.request). You are maybe confusing the usage of [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package with the inbuilt urllib library module.

---

```
>>> from urllib import request
>>> request.post
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'post'
```

Comment: You mean like `from urllib.request import post`?

Comment: @sitilge yes. Exactly that. :)